# Android getting Invalid Header Name using POST method

Tags: android, http

been trying to debug this issue to no avail.

I'm trying to pass a custom header to my POST request but I'm getting **Bad Request - Invalid Header Name**

This is my code:

```
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost(URL_LOGIN);

    try {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(KEY_EMAIL, etEmail.getText().toString()));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(KEY_PASSWORD, etPassword.getText().toString()));

        StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder();
        sbb.append("{\"s\":");
        sbb.append("\"" + session_id + "\",");
        sbb.append("\"n\":");
        sbb.append("\"" + getHashKey(ts, salt) + "\",");
        sbb.append("\"t\":");
        sbb.append("\"" + ts + "\"}");


        // Set HTTPPOST with your parameters
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params1));
        httppost.setHeader(Constants.DEVICE_HEADER, sbb.toString());

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // Setup an InputStream to handle the response.
        InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"iso-8859-1"), 8);

        // Use a reader to read the data and store it in a String builder
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;

        while(true) {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                break;
                sb.append(s);
        }

        buf.close();
        ips.close();

        Log.d("User Info", sb.toString());
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        Log.e("Is successful?", "" + jsonObj.getString(KEY_SUCCESS));

        if (jsonObj.getString(KEY_SUCCESS).equals("true")) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() { 
                      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                 }
             });
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() { 
                     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unauthorized user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
}
```

My header name is **device** but it's weird I'm getting this error for days. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks!

This is the log cat error message:

```
10-27 11:41:11.383: D/User Info(18162): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD><BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2><hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>   </BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Is your own developed webservice you are trying to connect to? Have you tried specifying the Content-Type?

Comment: @momo Yes I'm trying to connect to my webservice. And I also tried specifying the Content-Type

Comment: The client side code looks fine to me. Have you tried with cURL, Postman or similar? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en At this point I would debug or enable verbose logging in the server to see what is going on. If the server is not in production I would even try changing the header name from device to another value to see if the error message is really about the name.

Comment: @momo but if I hardcoded the header name and value it's working. I don't know why it's not working if I use StringBuilder

Comment: Try printing Constants.DEVICE_HEADER to make sure it is "device" without spaces or strange characters. Try printing the JSON to make sure you didn't forget any quote marks (although it looks like it is correct)

Comment: @momo thanks! I found the error. I have trimmed all my strings to find out that I have a whitespace character in my nonce variable. thanks for helping!

Comment: Glad you found it. Post an answer and accept it so the question doesn't stay unanswered ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I have a trailing whitespace in one of my variables.

So to fix,

```
nonce.trim();
```